# For a BJT determine unity bandwidth gain and emitter base capacitance

Tags: bjt

For a BJT operated at Ic=1mA,determine fT and Cπ if Cµ=2pF and \$|h_{fe}|= 10\$ at 50 MHz. This question is from Sedra Smith 6th edition exrecise 3.54.

My problem here is that since neither \$β_o\$ and \$r_π\$  are given. How would I solve for it since 
 \$h_{fe}= \frac{β_o}{1+s(Cπ+Cµ)r_π}\$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that :

$$h_{fe}= \frac{β_o}{1+s(Cπ+Cµ)r_π} = \frac{β_o}{\sqrt{1 +(Cπ+Cµ)^2\:{r_π}^2 }}$$
Additional we know thta: 
$$β_o = g_m r_{\pi}$$

And if we assume that this **50MHz** is \$1/\omega_B\$ we have

$$50\;\textrm{MHz} = \frac{1}{2\pi(Cπ+Cµ)r_π}$$

And from there we can solve for \$(Cπ+Cµ)r_π = 3.183 \cdot10^{-9}\$

So, we can solve for \$r_π\$ if \$g_m =40*I_C = 0.04 \:S \$

$$r_π = \frac{h_{fe}\sqrt{1 +\left((Cπ+Cµ)r_π\right)^2 } }{g_m} =\frac{10}{0.04} = 250\Omega$$

And if we know all of this we can solve for \$(Cπ+Cµ)\$ and \$\textrm{f}_T\$

$$(Cπ+Cµ) = \frac{(Cπ+Cµ)r_π }{r_π} = 12.72\textrm{pF} $$

$$\textrm{f}_T = \frac{g_m}{2\pi(Cπ+Cµ) }= 500\:\textrm{MHz}$$

Comment: That's exactly correct. I didn't know about the subsequent formula for hfe that you mentioned